# C# Windows Form TreeView Sort after LabelEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, treeview

After a node's label is edited in the tree I try to resort the nodes to place the updated item in the right position.  I do this by calling .Sort in AfterLabelEdit event handler which causes an infinite loop.

How can I resort the nodes in a treeview after a label has been changed?

Comment: One thing I found in MSDN's documentation:

Because the ListView..::.AfterLabelEdit event takes place before the label edit is committed, calling the ListView..::.Sort method in a handler for this event will sort the item using the original value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use BeginInvoke:

```
    delegate void sort();

    private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.BeginInvoke(new sort(treeView1.Sort));
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Use BeginInvoke with a MethodInvoker delegate instead of declaring your own delegate.

```
private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    treeView1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(treeView1.Sort));
}
```

Comment: Cool, this is a clean solution!