# Repositioning SelectedNode After Reordering TreeView Nodes in AfterLabelEdit Event

Tags: .net, winforms, events, treeview

[This was a very helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808696/c-sharp-windows-form-treeview-sort-after-labeledit) for sorting TreeView Nodes in AfterLabelEdit event.  It works great.  The only problem is that it changes SelectedNode and TopNode to the Root.  How can I get it to be the Node that was originally selected (now with a new text value) AND with TopNode set as it was before sorting?

Here is what my code looks like now:

```
Private Sub tvInventory_AfterLabelEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.NodeLabelEditEventArgs) Handles tvInventory.AfterLabelEdit
        tvInventory.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf tvInventory.Sort))
        e.CancelEdit = False
End Sub
```

I tried adding code to set the tvInventory.SelectedNode and tvInventory.TopNode values inside the AfterLabelEdit event handler but they are just ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face all along!  Use the same BeginInvoke method to restore my place outside the AfterLabelEdit event handler!  Final code looks like this:

```
Private Sub tvInventory_AfterLabelEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.NodeLabelEditEventArgs) Handles tvInventory.AfterLabelEdit
    SaveMyPlace()
    tvInventory.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf tvInventory.Sort))
    tvInventory.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf RestoreMyPlace))
    e.CancelEdit = False
End Sub

Private Sub SaveMyPlace()
    SavedSelectedNode = tvInventory.SelectedNode
    SavedTopNode = tvInventory.TopNode
End Sub

Private Sub RestoreMyPlace()
    tvInventory.SelectedNode = SavedSelectedNode
    tvInventory.TopNode = SavedTopNode
End Sub
```